# Extra blank page added using DinktoPDF

Tags: html, linux, wkhtmltopdf, page-break

I am using DinktoPDF library to generate PDFs. Mostly it works fine except for few occasions, it adds an extra blank page at the end of the document. It is happening on Linux when I am using Open Sans along with (PageSize, Page Orientation)  As (A4, Landscape).
I have a functionality to define different fonts and font size at the user level. I have applied lots of things(page breaks etc.) mentioned in different articles but issue still persists.

If anyone has any fix kindly share. Thanks in advance.

I have tried page breaks with no success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.